# WP8.1: Exporting data to "reachable" .txt file

Tags: c#, file, windows-phone-8.1, local-storage

I am creating an app that is tracking GPS data (latitude, longitude, altitude). So far I've managed to create a listbox that gets an extra line everytime another set of coordinates is made.

I tried writing it to file with this function.

```
     private async Task WriteToFile()
    {
        string ResultString = string.Join("\n", locationData.ToArray());

        byte[] fileBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ResultString);

        StorageFolder local = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        var dataFolder = await local.CreateFolderAsync("DataFolder", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
        var file = await dataFolder.CreateFileAsync("DataFile.txt", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

        using (var s = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
        {
            s.Write(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
        }
}
```

I can read this file, but I can't view this "DataFile.txt" anywhere in Files app.

I tried using WP Power Tools, but it doesn't work with 8.1, I am unable to update Visual Studio 2013 in order to get ISExplorer.exe working and 
IsoStoreSpy keeps crashing everytime I try to connect my Lumia 620.

But all of this looks too complitated to me. Is there any other way of getting this .txt file without messing with IsolatedStorage? I feel like I'm missing out on something so simple here, I just can't believe that such basic thing as writing output to .txt, that can be later used by PC, couldn't be available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're storing the file in your app's local storage (Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder), which is the same as Isolated Storage.

The Files app can see only public locations not app-specific locations.

There are several ways your app can share this file more globally:

1. Use the share contract to let the user share the file to wherever they'd like (OneNote, Email, etc.). See [Sharing and exchanging data](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh871373(v=win.10).aspx)
2. Let the user choose where to save the file with a [FileSavePicker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.storage.pickers.filesavepicker.aspx). See [How to save files through file pickers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/JJ150592(v=win.10).aspx)
3. Save the file on the SD card. See [Access the SD card in Windows Phone apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn611857.aspx).
4. Save the file to the user's OneDrive. See [Guidelines for accessing OneDrive from an app](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn263258.aspx)
5. Save to a RoamingFolder so the file can be read by the same app on a Windows PC, which can then export using similar methods (especially a file picker) but on the desktop device. See [Quickstart: Roaming app data](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh700362(v=win.10).aspx)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I tried to access the data using SD card - the link you provide gives me a chance to create folders/files from phone app. Yet those folders/files are not visible until I disconnect windows phone and connect it back via USB (I cannot see files even from windows explorer). How can I force/simulate a refresh in the usb contents from the desktop application (I am connecting via MTP). Without a way to auto refresh the contents from the PC side this solution will not work for me - I am trying to use this to communicate between PC application and phone application.